# Insufficient permissions to link to AdWords after creating analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've created an analytics account programmatically via the analytics provisioning API.  When I try and link that newly created account to an Adwords account I get the following error

```
exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 
'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/xxxxx/webproperties/UA-xxxxxxxxx-1/entityAdWordsLinks: (403) 
User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property.'
```

I visit the link at -  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxxxx and get the following output

```
{
 "issued_to": "xxxx-apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "xxxx-apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision",
 "expires_in": 1340,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

The scope that’s required is listed there, but I’m still getting the error.  How do I get around this error?  How do I ensure that the Adwords account has the proper permissions to link to Analytics accounts.  Why would I have permission to create the account but not modify the account I just created.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I got the same error and just can't seem to find whats wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764027/google-analytics-api-500-internal-error-during-adwords-link-creation/46764784?noredirect=1#comment80497455_46764784