# Google Analytics API 500 internal error during AdWords link creation

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I'm getting Error :

> "code":500,"message":"There was an internal error."

exception every time I'm trying to link Google analytics to Adwords via Analytics Management API.

Code is pretty straightforward (PHP), just like documentation example:

```
$adwordsAccounts = [];

foreach ($adwordsAccountIds as $customerId) {  
    $adwordsAccount = new \Google_Service_Analytics_AdWordsAccount();
    $adwordsAccount->setCustomerId($customerId);
    $adwordsAccount->setAutoTaggingEnabled(true);
    $adwordsAccounts[] = $adwordsAccount;
}

$adWordsLink = new \Google_Service_Analytics_EntityAdWordsLink();
$adWordsLink->setName('AdWords Link');
$adWordsLink->setAdWordsAccounts($adwordsAccounts);

$response = $client->management_webPropertyAdWordsLinks->insert($accountId, $webPropertyId, $adWordsLink);
```

google-api-php-client library version is latest (2.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

From [Account management](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management)

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete,
>   patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources are
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features, request access to the beta.

Unless i am mistaken you have not applied for access to the beta program.  Note it can take up to a month to get access you will hear from Google if you have been granted access.

Assuming that you have applied for beta.

There appears to be a bug in this currently the bug log can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63051481).   Google has been notified we will have to wait for them to fix it.

Comment: I think we already have that access, because I'm able to create properties, profiles and goals via API

Comment: Looks like this doesnt it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63051481

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? This issue is there from June and not seems to have any progress

Comment: it looks like it might be a bug.

Comment: So who should I write to speed it up? I worked with AdWords API before and support was really quick

Comment: add your comment to the bug report.  there's no way to speed it up they will get to it when they have time.   I can mention it when I meet with them next week but can't promise anything

Comment: Sure, did that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Somehow error 500 is not appearing anymore, I'm getting error 403 "User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property" instead. Even though I've just created that property via API. What could be the problem?

Comment: The user you are authentication with doesn't have access to that web property make sure they are by going to the Google analytics website in the admin section under users.

Comment: Email of my service account I'm authenticated with is set as admin with all permissions for corresponding Analytics account. I'm able to create properties/views under it via API.

Comment: Make sure its at the account level it has to be at the account level if you want to access web properties

Comment: I brought it up with the team they are going to have a look at it.

Comment: Are there any news about that?

Comment: I brought it up to them.   I dont think they were aware there was a problem.   This should mean they will be looking into it.  Any response from them will show up on the bug report.